# PHP Keyword Search Duplicate & Incorrect Results

Tags: php, mysql

Simple search worked when I was only searching one table but tried to add two tables and things went screwy. Now it returns all rows in a db whether or not they contain searched keywords and each row outputs twice.

```
if(isset($_GET['keywords'])):
$keywords = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['keywords']);
$sql = "
SELECT p.topic, s.title
FROM table_posts p, table_sheets s
WHERE p.topic LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
OR s.title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
";
$query = $db->query($sql);

?>
  <div class="result-count">
    <p>Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.</p><br>
  </div>
<?php

if($query->num_rows):
while($row = $query->fetch_object()):
  $weight = substr_count(strtoupper($row->topic), strtoupper($keywords));
?>
  <div class="result">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $weight . ' ' . $row->topic; ?></a>
  </div>
  <br>
<?php
  endwhile;
 endif;
endif;
```

Returns something like regardless of keywords:

> 1 Row 1 Data 
>   1 Row 1 Data
>   0 Row 2 Data
>   0 Row 2 Data
>   1 Row 3 Data
>   1 Row 3 Data
>   ...

Comment: you tried the same with a join ? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Your forget to write : `$query->execute();` before fetching

Answer (score 0):

You should have some relation between the two tables. So only it retrieve the correct outputs. Query should something like...

```
$sql = "SELECT p.topic, s.title 
FROM table_posts p, table_sheets s 
WHERE p.topic   LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR s.title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
AND p.SOME_ID_LIKE_id = s.SOME_RELATED_ID_LIKE_topic_id
";
```

OR u have use UNION to retrieve data